# Rebuilding XML structure into a recursive style list / XMLReader alternative

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

**Issue:**

I have been trying to parse xml, and create an object for each node in the XML.

**The problem:**

As my xml has nodes in any order, and some are child nodes of other nodes, I am struggling to logically parse them without using .net 1.1 and the XmlNode classes.

**Note** : I wish to use only XMLReader as I am restricted to .Net Standard 1.0 and do not want to install any extra libraries.
( see here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Currently I create an object for each xml node, each object contains a list of child components which i wish to add to, should it find a child node. However i cannot seem to recursively search the xml and generate the structure into a list/list of lists correctly.

**My code**:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static List<UIComponent> components = new List<UIComponent>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test.xml";
        parseXML(path);
    }


    private static UIComponent addToLowestChild(UIComponent parent, UIComponent child)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<parent.getChildren().Count;++i)
        { 

            if (parent.getChildren().Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (UIComponent kid1 in parent.getChildren())
                {
                    if (kid1.getChildren().Count > 0)
                    {
                        addToLowestChild(kid1, child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return parent;
    }

    private static UIComponent ChildTest(int depth,UIComponent parent,UIComponent child)
    {
        //i=depth for item 4, if i is set to 1 first
        for (int i = 1; i < depth; ++i)
            {
                if (parent.getChildren().Count > 0)
                {
                    if (i > 1)
                    {
                    ChildTest(i, parent.getChildren()[parent.getChildren().Count - 1], child);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    parent.getChildren()[parent.getChildren().Count - 1].addChild(child);
                    break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.addChild(child);
                    break;
                }
            }


        return parent;
    }

    private static void parseXML(string path)
    {
        //read the xml file into one string
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        string xmlContent = "";
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            xmlContent += line;
        }

        UIComponent currentComponent = null;

        //parse the xml content
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlContent)))
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                int currentDepth = 0;
                // Console.WriteLine(reader.Name+" depth:"+reader.Depth);
                if (reader.Depth > 0) //ignore ground level elements such as <XML> and <UI>
                {


                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            if (currentComponent == null || reader.Depth==currentDepth)
                            {
                                currentComponent = new UIComponent(reader.Name);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                UIComponent childComponent = new UIComponent(reader.Name);
                                //currentComponent.addChild(childComponent);
                                ChildTest(reader.Depth,currentComponent,childComponent);
                            }
                            break;

                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            if (reader.Depth == 1 && currentComponent!=null)
                            {
                                components.Add(currentComponent);
                                currentComponent = null;
                            }
                            break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**My Test Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UI>
  <window x="5">
    <Button2 value="">
        <Button3 y="">
        </Button3>
        <Button4>
            <Button6 value=""></Button6>
            <Button5 value=""></Button5>
        </Button4>
    </Button2>
  </window>
  <window></window>
  <heading></heading>
</UI>
```

The output:

```
-Window
  |-Button 2
    |-- Button 3
    |-- Button 4
    |-- Button 6
    |-- Button 5
-Window
-Heading
```

What I want:

```
-Window
  |-Button 2
    |-- Button 3
    |-- Button 4
        |-- Button 6
        |-- Button 5
-Window
-Heading
```

Comment: Here's from the description of XmlReader: "*Represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data*".What makes you think you can actually add to it?

Comment: What is *.net 1.0*?

Comment: I updated the question to address this for any future readers. Thank you for the help @IvanStoev!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is to maintain a stack of the currently processing nodes. Anytime you hit the `StartElement`, you create a new node, read the attributes, add it to the parent or root node list, and if it's not empty an element (like `<window />`), push it to the stack. And when you hit `EndElement` you simply pop (remove) the last element of the stack. The stack top element represents the currently processing node.

Putting it into action, parsing XML to list of simple class like this:

```
class Node
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

could be something like this:

```
static List<Node> ParseXML(string xmlContent)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlContent)))
    {
        var rootNodes = new List<Node>();
        var nodeStack = new Stack<Node>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    var node = new Node { Name = reader.Name };
                    if (reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                    {
                        // Read the attributes
                        do
                        {
                            node.Attributes.Add(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                        }
                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute());
                        // Move back to element
                        reader.MoveToElement();
                    }
                    var nodes = nodeStack.Count > 0 ? nodeStack.Peek().Children : rootNodes;
                    nodes.Add(node);
                    if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
                        nodeStack.Push(node);
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    nodeStack.Pop();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return rootNodes;
    }
```